# LINQ: Build dynamic filter with sequence of ANDs

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-expressions

I'm struggling to dynamically create a query like that:

```
Dictionary<string, Guid> parms = new Dictionary<string, Guid>();

foreach (var kvp in parms)
{
    var exp = ReportDefinitions.Where(x=> 
        x.Discriminants.Any(y=> y.Key == kvp.Key && y.Value == kvp.Value)
// && more conditions to add here at each cycle
        );  
}
```

Where ReportDefinitions.Discriminants is an `IDictionary<string, Guid>`;
I know how to build simple Expression but I can't figure out how to build this one the "Any" seems really complicated.
The Any call it's hard to undestand

Anyone knows how to deal with this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var query = parms.Aggregate(ReportDefinitions.AsQueryable(),
  (a, kvp) => a.Where(x => x.Discriminants.Any(
     y => y.Key == kvp.Key && y.Value == kvp.Value)));
```

We are starting with an unfiltered query of ReportDefinitions and are folding in all query params. The end result is a sequence of nested filters which is equivalent to a sequence of ANDs.

The key insight is that this process maps nicely to a *reduce* known from functional languages. LINQ to objects supports it via `Aggregate`.

Comment: I want to thank you immediately, seems a simple solution. I'm actually from a mobile device, I'll try your solution as soon as a few hours.

Comment: Works excellently, and the underlying Expression is almost the same as the one I was trying to build with a huge amount of Expression. thanks again, I just learnt something new